How to Sculpt Grease Pencil Strokes Along the Y-Axis?
Can a Grease Pencil stroke be sculpted on the Y-axis? It doesn’t seem like it can, and I’m guessing it’s because it’s not a mesh. Before I try converting it to a mesh, I’m wondering if I’m missing something here. The effect I'm trying to achieve can be seen here at @1:23:
As the artist has done here, I made a drawing and then isolated parts, moving them slightly forward and back on the Y-axis. This achieves a fairly decent 3D effect while panning a small distance. What I am trying to do now is bend the lines a bit, so when panning, the lines curve more gently in front of the camera.

To answer your question:

Can a grease pencil stroke be sculpted on the Y axis?

Yes, it depends on the Drawing Plane setting you’re using. By default, drawing and sculpting occur on the Front (X-Z) plane. If you’d like to draw or sculpt along the Y-axis, simply change the Drawing Plane to Side (Y-Z). For more details on the different Drawing Plane modes, refer to the documentation on Drawing Plane.

